# how to get start and end on date and time range picker?

Tags: javascript, mysql, daterangepicker

I can't see how to get the start and end from a date and time range picker I usually use `data-link-field="dtp_input1"` to get the data to insert into a table like I code it like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="dtp_input1" name="date" value="" /><br/>
```

Now my code from date and time range picker is like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Date and time range:</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <div class="input-group-addon"> <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>

        </div>
        <input type="text" class="form-control pull-right" id="reservationtime">
    </div>
    <!-- /.input group -->
</div>
<!-- /.form group -->
```

and for the javascript:

```
 $('#reservationtime').daterangepicker({
     timePicker: true,
     timePickerIncrement: 30,

     format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
 });
```

[please see my screenschot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yc3pZ.jpg)

how can i code to get start and end and enter it on mysql database

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#reservationtime').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true, timePickerIncrement: 30, 
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A'
}).bind('datepicker-change',function(event, obj)    
    /* This event will be triggered when second date is selected */
    console.log('change',obj);
    // obj will be something like this:
    // {
    //      date1: (Date object of the earlier date),
    //      date2: (Date object of the later date),
    //      value: "2013-06-05 to 2013-06-07"
    // }
})
```

Comment: how can i enter the data of start and end on database?

Comment: There are a lot options, e.g. you can make an AJAX request using `$.ajax` with payload being set to the dates or you can create a hidden field that you will update accordingly (it will be posted along with the form submission)

Comment: I want to use hidden but I don't know how to apply data-link-field within same picker? a sample will be much appreciated